# python unittest mock - checking a function returned at the correct point

Tags: python, mocking, unit-testing

I have a method which looks like this:

```
def foo(self):
    if not self.started:
        self.start()
        return None

    # do some other stuff...
    self.bar()
    return self.baz()
```

I am writing a test called `test_foo_calls_start_if_not_already_started_and_then_returns_immediately`.

Testing if we called `start` is easy:

```
with mock.patch.object(Thing, 'start') as mock_start:
    thing = Thing()
    thing.foo()
    self.assertTrue(mock_start.called)
```

But how would I test that the function then returns straight after?  I guess I could mock bar and baz and check that they aren't called, but that would be a pain to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to know without seeing more code, but I would say that a technique is to use the very next function call on `self` and assert that was not called. And also if None is only returned if not started, you have strong point there.

Assuming `self.bar()` is the immediate call, patch `bar` and then just check that it was not called, as easy as...

```
assert not mock_start.calls
```

I however prefer to have very short unittests, and monkey-patch the methods (if not using some kind of dependency injection), instead of using the context manager. The partially mocked object is anyway discarded right away, so it is safe to do so. Something like this:

```
def test1(self):
  thing = Thing()
  thing.started = False  # Maybe it would make sense to include this
  thing.start = Mock()
  thing.bar = Mock()

  res = thing.foo()
  assert res is None
  assert thing.start.called
  assert not thing.bar.called
```

The mocking frameworks can ease a lot the testing activities, but at the end the testability boils down to your code and its quality. General hints are: return meaningful values, re-factor your code into smaller methods that allow checking calls more precisely, either mutate state or return a value, but not both, etc.

Comment: yeh, this is along the lines of what I mentioned at the bottom of the question.  This is ok, but if the function was more complex, e.g. perhaps there is a long if...elif block at the top, i'd have to check that all the possible next function calls were not called.

Comment: I would suggest to re-factor your function. Keep it small, move out code to other functions (for instance the possible `if...elif` block) and check calls to these other functions, return clear things (feels strange to return None if not started, and something else otherwise). There is always a way.

Comment: how would you refactor the function in my question?

Comment: I can't say without seeing your real code, sorry. But if it is as you are showing, there is no big deal testing it.